# Java difficult regular expression, how to mathc groups (tripples)?

Tags: java, regex

How can I check in regex that 3 of the same digits must appear next to each other and that 1x or more times?

For example `333bbwjdi` should be correct, because `333` is in there but `33bbwjdi` should be false, because I don't have a triple.

Answer (score 2):

you can use below regular expression:

```
(\d)\1\1
```

Where:

- \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- \1 matches the same text as
  most recently matched by the 1st capturing group

or:

```
(\d)\1{2}
```

Which does the same thing: matching same text as before twice

Comment: Yes, it does the work. But it can be simplified with a qualifier seems :)

Comment: Yes, a quantifier (`{2}`) saves -1 characters. /s

Comment: It can be used as `\d{3}`. They do the same thing.

Comment: Plz make sure to format code properly next time ;)

Comment: @Henryc17 no, `\d{3}` would match `123` - which is not the same.

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn, yea, just figured it out. thx for your reminder :)